# CakePHP: Find across multiple models

Tags: cakephp

I have several models that all share one fields (say name) but differ in other fields. Is there any wan to find all of ModelX ModelY and ModelZ that have name 'foo'. Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: If you have a field that is a replication of data from another table that is not a simple ID, you're probably doing it wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this ?

```
$models = array('Post', 'Comment', 'Article');
$results = array();

foreach($models as $model) {
    $this->loadModel($model);
    $results[$model] = $this->{$model}->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            $model'.name' => $name
        )
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If the they are related you should be able to specify the Model followed by '.' within the find.

```
    $this->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array(
             'OR' => array(
                  'Article.field' => 'foo',
                  'Comment.field' => 'foo',
                  'Post.field' => 'foo',
              )
         ),
        'fields' => array('Article.field', 'Comment.field', 'Post.field')
    ));
```